# Am I understanding this first order formula correctly?

Tags: first-order-logic

The formula is:

$\forall x \; \exists y \; ( y < x \land \forall z (z < x \rightarrow \lnot y < z ))$

The way I understand it, it says for all $x$, there exists a $y$ such that $y < x$ and for all $z$, if $z < x$, then $y \le z$.

For the sets U = $\Bbb Z$ and U = $\Bbb R$, would this be true?

In the case y + 1 = x, that would be true, so there does exist a y. Or am I supposed to see if this is true for all y? (In which case it wouldn't be.)

Comment: if $z<x$, then $y \ge z$.

Comment: Oops! Yeah that's what I meant. Apart from that slip up, is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @fasdfagwe: Yes, it is. Another way to say it: each $x$ has an immediate predecessor. Yes, it’s true for $\Bbb Z$: for any $x\in\Bbb Z$ you can take $y=x-1$, and the expression in parentheses becomes true. Try to show that it’s not true if $U=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it would be false for real numbers, but that makes sense. Using the idea of immediate predecessor, wouldn't it be because there's no way of knowing what the immediate predecessor is for x? That is, since there are an infinite amount of real numbers between two integers?